# how to execute php file from android class using the Post method

Tags: php, android

I want to execute the php url from android and pass the two values while executing the url.

Here is the code I use. I used `GET` method but I need to send it as POST variable.

How can I change the request from `GET` variable to `POST` variable in the below code:

```
public class AsyncTaskOperation extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... paramsObj)
    {

        //Sending the php file path 
        String php_send="http://localhost/tested/test/copy_fiel.php?Cus="+Cus+"&"+"Cut_fol="+Cut_fol;

        System.out.println(php_send);
        // want to execute the above path using Http client but it is not working 
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(php_send);

        try {   
            HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httpGet);
            System.out.println(resp);        
        }         
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you remove subscribe validation question ?

Comment: @Haresh ya i deleted that and i know that u have given negative reputation

Comment: No i haven't given negative vote to you and im asking becz i done code for your problem.

Comment: @Haresh ya i want help bro in that code pls help

Comment: @Haresh i have not deleted that can u help now please ...I have again posted ..bro

Comment: @Haresh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009406/edittext-error-solved-then-enable-the-send-button-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NameValuePair with HttpPost, it will work:

```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/myexample.php");

try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Cus", Cus));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Cut_fol", Cut_fol));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Asynchttp client. I find it easier to set it post or get

To post data:
- Create a parameters object, 
- put in your values and post to the url.

Code sample is as follows:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
params.put("msg","Hello world");
url="[Your URL]";
client.post(url,params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        super.onStart();                                                
                    }
                   @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
                    }
  );
```

You can get the library here

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: but i want to add parameters like how i am sending two parameters Cus and Cut_fol

Comment: If you look at the example carefully, there is a params.put functions. You can add as many parameters as you wish. 
so it should be ...
params.put("Cus",Cus);
params.put("Cut_fol",Cut_fol);