# errors while implementing textwatcher to verify password input

Tags: android, eclipse, textwatcher

while trying to implement a registration page that send user data to server i want to validate whether user has given same passwords in both text boxes,  my code seems to contain errors, "settings_pwd_equal" cannot be resolved into a type, make it a field or a variable?

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;
EditText inputPassword2;
final TextView error = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.TextView_PwdProblem);

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    inputPassword2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword2);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);





    inputPassword2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              String strPass1 = inputPassword.getText().toString();
              String strPass2 = inputPassword2.getText().toString();
              if (strPass1.equals(strPass2)) {
                 error.setText(R.string.settings_pwd_equal);
              } else {
                 error.setText(R.string.settings_pwd_not_equal);
              }
           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
         });
```

Comment: Check out this my ans will help you to solve your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009406/edittext-error-solved-then-enable-the-send-button-in-android/25011488#25011488

Comment: final TextView error = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.TextView_PwdProblem); How can you able to declare this widget globally? remove this line. and try again

Comment: @Haresh your answer compares strings it doesnt seem to use textwatcher to compare passwords

Comment: So have you think is it right way to compare two password field at input time ?

Comment: i think i can use your compare statement inside the implementation of textwatcher...

Comment: public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                    {  // your code to compare strings  textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText(match/not match) }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use String resource in java file, use this:

```
error.setText(context.getString(R.string.settings_pwd_equal));
error.setText(context.getString(R.string.settings_pwd_not_equal));
```

Refer [Accessing Resource in code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromCode)

Hope this helps.